# Unable to tag a GIT repo from a rake task

Tags: git, teamcity, rake, rake-task, git-tag

I have created a rake task to tag a build which runs from a `Teamcity` pipeline. It's a simple task using below commands:

```
git tag
git push
```

It runs perfectly well from the local machine. However, it fails when I run the same task from a pipeline with the error message:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Can someone help me to understand this?

Comment: Please put the full log here. would be better if you specify the commands properly.

Answer (score 0):

AS the message says: those commands are being executed in a directory which doesn't belong to a git repository. (Said differently: neither the current directory, nor any of its parent, contains a `.git` directory).

You could have your script run `pwd` to understand from where those commands are being run. (If it appears to be the expected directory, then you might want to run `ls -a` from the root of the expected git repo, to ensure there's a `.git` directory)

Comment: I tried it from the correct path. still its the same.

Answer (score 0):

Teamcity has a build in functionality to do this, in the build features -> VCS Labeling.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLpSl.png)

Comment: Thanks. I will check this